# Black screen after waking from suspend

Tags: 16.04, suspend, laptop, macbook, macbook-air

After reinstalling Ubuntu 16.04 on my MacBook Air suspend doesn't work properly. I am able to suspend, and able to wake my laptop again, only the screen is entirely black.

No matter what I do, it stays black. I have tried entering TTYs, restarting `lightdm` over ssh, but nothing works. I know the computer is on, since I am able to access it over ssh.

**Update:** I have found that the problem only occurs when booting with the `nomodeset` option. Apparently this option lets the kernel handle the graphics, and as pointed out by [@kukulo](https://askubuntu.com/users/395048/kukulo) there is a bug in the kernel. I can boot without this option, but that makes my graphics and boot time significantly slower, so I am still looking for a solution to this problem. I tried upgrading the kernel to the latest stable release, but I am still seeing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the kernel, try to update to 4.4.8 kernel according this:

```
sudo apt-get -y install linux-image-4.8.0-58-generic
```

I have 16.04 on samsung n145 and after upgrading the kernel I can at least suspend from menu an wake up laptop via power button.

Note: The 4.4.0-112 kernel runs also fine on the n145, also the [Meltdown](https://meltdownattack.com/) patch is included. The included Atom processor is immune against [Spectre](https://meltdownattack.com/) attack.

Comment: I just upgraded to 4.10.8 which is the latest kernel, but I am still experiencing the issue. Do you think I should downgrade to 4.4.8?

Comment: Can you suspend from menu?

Comment: No, same result

Comment: With the 4.4.8 I can suspend at least from menu, with closing lid I have the same problem as before. I had earlier 14.04 installed and suspend with closing lid worked.

Comment: Are you booting with the `nomodeset` option? Just wondering how related our problems are before I try downgrading the kernel

Comment: No, I was not booting with nomodeset. I tried to set it: actually it has no effect to sleep function. When I closed the lid, the behavior was the same as before. I am able to suspend from shutdown menu though.

Comment: That ubuntumaniac.com link apparently is dead; perhaps you can edit answer to include whatever it said, or find a different link